# ABAP Short Dump on append of a sorted table

Tags: abap

Why does my ABAP program short dump when I append a line to a sorted table?

ST22 Shows `ITAB_ILLEGAL_SORT_ORDER`

```
data: sorted_tab type sorted table of ty_tab with non-unique key key,
      line       type ty_tab.

line-key = 1. 
append line to sorted_tab.  "works fine" 

line-key = 2. 
append line to sorted_tab.  "works fine" 

line-key = 1. 
append line to sorted_tab.  "<==== Short dump here"
```

Comment: This seems like a stupid question - but I've just wasted enough time to find the answer to save the next person some grief.  (Google was helpful, SAP help was not)

Comment: please include the declaration of your sorted table!

Comment: good point - as if your table was declared with a unique key you would get yet another short dump

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The program short dumps when appending a sorted table *in the wrong sort order*

```
data: sorted_tab type sorted table of ty_tab with non-unique key key,
      line       type ty_tab.

line-key = 1.
append line to sorted_tab.  "works fine"

line-key = 2.
append line to sorted_tab.  "works fine"

line-key = 1.
append line to sorted_tab.  "<==== Short dump here"
```

Use INSERT in stead:

```
data: sorted_tab type sorted table of ty_tab with non-unique key key,
      line       type ty_tab.

line-key = 1.
insert line into table sorted_tab.  "works fine"

line-key = 2.
insert line into table sorted_tab.  "works fine"    

line-key = 1.
insert line into table sorted_tab.  "works fine"
```

*Note* If you had a *UNIQUE* key you would still get a short dump because you're using the same key twice